# Efficient way of searching for a string in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I would like to come up with an efficient way of finding a string in a `data.frame` *including* the values stored in row names.

## Present approach

Primitively, I can achieve that running this code:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$rows <- row.names(mtcars)
sapply(mtcars, function(x) { grep("mazda",x, ignore.case = TRUE) })
```

I don't like it as it returns data for all columns:

```
> length(sapply(mtcars, function(x) { grep("mazda",x, ignore.case = TRUE) }))
[1] 12
```

I would like to prettify this code so it only returns:

- column name for successful match
- row name for successful match
- in format **column** X **row**

---

## Additional considerations

- Following suggestions expressed in comments, it occurred to me that I would also like to search **column names,** if possible.

Comment: Something like this? `which(apply(mtcars,2, function(x) { grepl("mazda",x, ignore.case = TRUE) }), arr.ind = T)` ?

Comment: @Jimbou Definitely prettier to what I've but I would like to drop the `mtcars$rows <- row.names(mtcars)` line as well. Ideally, I will later make function out of it and run it when search for epiphany aka *is that value somewhere there or I filtered it out*?

Comment: @Jimbou Sorry, I wasn't sufficiently clear in my request. I want to search *whole* data frame including row name and column names and return some information on the placement of a specific string. This string may be in column name, may be in row name or (most probably) will be simply one of values in `data.frame`.

Comment: @Jimbou I reckon I could push `names` and `row.names` to vectors in a list and search all of that. Having said that, I was hoping that maybe there is some fancy way of searching a *whole* object.

Comment: Get it now :) Not sure if this is generally possible. You can rbind the colnames to the data.frame then you can grep all values. But this is not your desired output. `rbind(colnames(mtcars),mtcars)`

Comment: I don't think you can get around handling names separately. The most idiomatic way to find values within the dataframe is probably `arrayInd(grep("searchtext", unlist(mtcars)), dim(mtcars))`

Comment: @Jimbou Thanks for showing the interest any way. I'll leave it here for a while and see what happens. It also crossed my mind to somehow transform the whole data frame to a vector and then search through it but I would find it difficult to pinpoint the location of the value.

Comment: @Hav0k Nevertheless, thank you very much for suggesting a viable approach. Worst case scenario, a simple function could push row and column names to values and then search.

Comment: "*in format column X row*" is not very clear. How would that work for column names? Also, your desired out put included only the length. Can you please show your desired output with some representative data set, or else this is very unclear question...

Comment: What is the use case for this function, do we ultimately want to know if the dataframe is about "mazda" or not, then outcome should be logical TRUE/FALSE?

Comment: @zx8754 I have long and unreadable data frames that were transformed on countless occasions. I would like to be able to search for strings on the same basis as you would search and ordinary text with `grep` to figure out where the string may be.

Comment: Read the data without setting header and rownames. than you have everything in one data.frame: `read.table("files", row.names = NULL, header=F)`.

Comment: @Jimbou Actually, it could do. I was thinking of exporting and existing object to a file and then reading it with no row.names and no names, this would work in terms of creating a neat searchable object (it would be a lot of hassle to read CSVs and go through all the transformations).